Problem with GLIBC when running executable on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B
I created a executable file on the raspberry pi 3 using pyinstaller. Did the regular changes to the .spec to include my other files and attempted to run it... Nothing. So, I went into terminal and input:
(dev_venv) myName@raspberrypi: ~/PYTHON_CODE/dist/Resistance_Tester $ file Resistance_Tester

which worked out because it showed:
Resistance_Tester: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV)...

So, I tried to execute using the following:
(dev_venv) myName@raspberrypi: ~/PYTHON_CODE/dist/Resistance_Tester $ ./Resistance_Tester

and the response to my request to run was this:
./Resistance_Tester: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by ./Resistance_Tester)
./Resistance_Tester: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by ./Resistance_Tester)

my current version of debian using ldd is Debian GLIBC 2.31. Is there an easy fix to get the executable working on this Raspberry Pi? I am not experienced with pyinstaller or creating executables, but I wasn't sure if using a previous version of pyinstaller would fix this issue for the time being, or if I should just use a newer raspberry pi? Any help with this issue is greatly appreciated.

I have found out that the version of Raspberry Pi OS 11 does not include the glibc that is required to use pyinstaller. I have since imaged Raspberry Pi OS 12 onto my Raspberry Pi and have been able to use pyinstaller flawlessly. Compatibility issue.
